# Surfaces formed by infinitesmal equilateral triangles at common vertices

Tags: tiling, noneuclidean-geometry

Say we have equilateral triangles coming together at a common vertex with each angle is $ 2 \pi/n= 2 \pi/6$.  As the hexagon side tends to zero we have a flat plane defined with hexagonally packed tiling and the Gauss curvature of the plane

$$K_6=0$$

Now in a similar manner $K_7, K_8$ repeated 3d tiling would form surfaces of negative curvature as $ \text{side of triangle}\to 0$, a defined polyhedral solid angle forms.

How to parameterize the surface in order to visualize it?

Thanks for all pointers, how to use GB theorem and so on..

Comment: How do you propose to join seven equilateral triangles at a vertex? You have to specify some kind of series of dihedral angles to allow them to fit.

Comment: I prepared cardboard models long ago. one radius in  a hexagon is cut, interposed in an extra equilateral triangle to warp around the common vertex.

Comment: Right, but there are multiple ways that you can fit 7 triangles around a vertex when you allow them to bend in the third dimension. Without a precise specification of how you'd like this to happen, it's hard to know what parameterization is correct.

Comment: Keeping the dihedral angle of adjacent faces constant, i.e, when three edge points  make congruent isosceles triangles along the warped edge.

Comment: In a simpler hyperbolic paraboloid like geometry  for example four angles sum up to more than $ 360^{\circ}$